# jQuery onselected for a option, how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select>
            <option value="0" id="n">n</option>
            <option value="1" id="m">m</option>
</select>
```

In jQuery, how do I say:

When id "n" is **selected**...do this . (not onclick) I want onSelected.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the change eventhandler

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `onclick` for each `option` tag, I recomment use `onchange` event of `select`. Another advantage of writing this will be you don't need to care event bubbling or event capturing and you have one method declared on `select` tag.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use id's for options inside a select tag.

```
$(function(){
    $("#sel1").change(function(){
        switch($(this).val())
        {
            case "0": // do your code
                      break;
        }
    });
});
<select id="sel1">
            <option value="0" id="n">n</option>
            <option value="1" id="m">m</option>
</select>
```